# What is this error LNK2019 and 1120

Tags: c++, class, constructor, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//In this section I create the class HotelRoom

class HotelRoom
{
protected:
    HotelRoom(){}
    char room_Number[4];
    char* guestName;
    double rate;

public:

    HotelRoom(char Num[], double daily, char* name);
    HotelRoom(const HotelRoom &);
    ~HotelRoom();
    int Get_Capacity();
    int Get_Status();
    double Get_Rate();
    const char* Get_Number();
    const char* Get_Guest();
    int Change_Status(int Stat);
};

HotelRoom::HotelRoom(char Num[], double daily, char* name)
{
    strcpy_s(room_Number, 4, Num);
    guestName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(guestName, 20, name);
    rate = daily;
}
HotelRoom::HotelRoom(const HotelRoom& room_r)
{
    strcpy_s(room_Number, room_r.room_Number);
    guestName = new char[strlen(room_r.guestName) + 1];
    strcpy_s(guestName, 20, room_r.guestName);
    rate = room_r.rate; 
}
HotelRoom::~HotelRoom()
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Decunstructor Activated." << endl;
    delete[] guestName;
}

double HotelRoom::Get_Rate()
{
    return rate;
}
const char* HotelRoom::Get_Number()
{
    return room_Number;
}
const char* HotelRoom::Get_Guest()
{
    return guestName;
}
class DerivedGuestRoom : public HotelRoom
{
public:
    DerivedGuestRoom(int max, int stat, int nights);
    DerivedGuestRoom(const DerivedGuestRoom&);
    ~DerivedGuestRoom();

protected:
    int capacity;
    int status = 0; //0 if unoccupied
    int days;

};

DerivedGuestRoom::DerivedGuestRoom(int max, int stat, int nights) :  capacity(max), status(stat), days(nights)
{
    cout << "data members set";
}

DerivedGuestRoom::~DerivedGuestRoom()
{
    cout << "\ndecunstrucor";
}
class DerivedMeetingRoom : public HotelRoom
{
public:
    DerivedMeetingRoom(int seat, int stat);
    DerivedMeetingRoom(const DerivedMeetingRoom&);
    ~DerivedMeetingRoom();

protected:
    int seats;
    int status; //1 if booked for meeting 0 otherwise
};
DerivedMeetingRoom::DerivedMeetingRoom(int seat, int stat) : seats(seat), status(stat)
{
    cout << "data members set";
}

DerivedMeetingRoom::~DerivedMeetingRoom()
{
    cout << "\ndecunstrucor";
}
void Display_info(HotelRoom&);
HotelRoom* Create_Hotel();
int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(2)
        << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
        << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

    HotelRoom* Hotel_Rooms[200];

    int count = 0;
    char response;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to enter information about a hotel room?(Y/N): ";
    response = cin.get();
    cin.get();

    while (toupper(response) == 'Y' && count < 10)
    {
        Hotel_Rooms[count] = Create_Hotel();
        ++count;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to enter information about a hotel room?(Y/N): ";
        response = cin.get();
        cin.get();
    }
    //Display the accounts created
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        Display_info(*Hotel_Rooms[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        delete Hotel_Rooms[i];

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void Display_info(HotelRoom& room)
{
    cout << "\n\nGuest's Name: " << room.Get_Guest() << endl << endl;

    cout << "\nYour room number is " << room.Get_Number() << endl << endl;

    cout << "\nDaily rate is: " << room.Get_Rate() << endl << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
HotelRoom* Create_Hotel()
{
    //These are the variables that will be holding data then passed through objects

    char roomNumber[4];
    char guestName[20];

    double dailyRate = 89.00;

    HotelRoom* room_ptr;

    //This portion asks for user input

    cout << "\nEnter Guest information\n\n";

    cout << "Enter the room number: ";
    cin.getline(roomNumber, 4);

    cout << "Enter the guest's name: ";
    cin.getline(guestName, 20);
    cout << endl;

    cin.get(); //Clears input buffer

    room_ptr = new HotelRoom(roomNumber, dailyRate, guestName);

    return room_ptr;
}
```

I took out HotelRoom(); from parent class constructor and I removed from the child class constructors. I Now only have this error:

LearningOOP.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Which I have never encountered this so not sure what it means.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined your default constructor for the HotelRoom class.

```
class HotelRoom
{
protected:
    char room_Number[4];
    char* guestName;
    double rate;

public:
    HotelRoom(); //< Not defined!
    HotelRoom(char Num[], double daily, char* name);
    HotelRoom(const HotelRoom &);
    ~HotelRoom();
    int Get_Capacity();
    int Get_Status();
    double Get_Rate();
    const char* Get_Number();
    const char* Get_Guest();
    int Change_Status(int Stat);
};
```

An "Unresolved external symbol" linker error means that you've declared and used a piece of code in your application, but you haven't defined it before using it.

EDIT (Based on your follow up comment below):

You can't take the constructor *out* because it's needed in other parts of your code. See this line in your code:

```
DerivedGuestRoom::DerivedGuestRoom(int max, int stat, int nights) : HotelRoom(), capacity(max), status(stat), days(nights)
//                                                                  ^---------^
//                                                                       |
//                                                            Using the default constructor.

DerivedMeetingRoom::DerivedMeetingRoom(int seat, int stat) : HotelRoom(), seats(seat), status(stat)
//                                                           ^---------^
//                                                                |
//                                                         And again here!
```

You either need to remove implement the default constructor for the `HotelRoom` class, or add parameters to your `DerivedMeetingRoom` and `DerivedGuestRoom` class constructors so that you can use the `HotelRoom(char Num[], double daily, char* name)` constructor.

Comment: I was telling OldProgrammer that if I take out HotelRoom(); that I get these errors:

Comment: Error 1 error C2512: 'HotelRoom' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\learningoop\learningoop\classesandmore.cpp 77 1 LearningOOP
Error 2 error C2512: 'HotelRoom' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\learningoop\learningoop\classesandmore.cpp 97 1 LearningOOP

Comment: See the edit to my post :)

Comment: @SyntaxEyes - Where does it trigger a breakpoint?

For future reference, you shouldn't edit your question for an unrelated error, you should create a new question or add a comment. People looking for the same linker error code will get confused by your unrelated question!

Comment: I do appoligize, I didn't even think about that, I will keep in mind. To answer your question it breakpoints at the end of program, more specific, when I enter 'n' when it asks to enter new information.

Comment: @SyntaxEyes - Does it give an error code or an explanation for the break? Or does it just say "triggered a breakpoint"?

Comment: it only says "triggered a breakpoint"

Answer (score 2):

You declared a default constructor:

```
class HotelRoom
{
public:
  HotelRoom();
}
```

and there is no implementation for that default constructor method.  You can change to:

```
class HotelRoom
{
public:
  HotelRoom() {}
}
```

or implement `HotelRoom:HotelRoom { }` in your cpp file.

Comment: I Noticed when I take out HotelRoom() I get these errors:

Comment: Error 1 error C2512: 'HotelRoom' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\learningoop\learningoop\classesandmore.cpp 77 1 LearningOOP
Error 2 error C2512: 'HotelRoom' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\learningoop\learningoop\classesandmore.cpp 97 1 LearningOOP

Comment: @SyntaxEyes No-one is telling you to take out `HotelRoom()` they are telling you to *define* it. All you've done is *declare* it. Declaring it is like a promise to the compiler that it exists. Now you've got to follow through on that promise and define `HotelRoom::HotelRoom()`. You've already decalred and defined everything else in your program, so I'm not sure why this one is a stumbling block.

Comment: @OldProgrammer the reason I took HotelRoom() out was because I don't need it. The only reason I put it in was because it got rid of the error I shown you just now.

Comment: @SyntaxEyes You say you don't need it, but you use it here `DerivedMeetingRoom::DerivedMeetingRoom(int seat, int stat) : HotelRoom(), seats(seat), status(stat)`, (same also for `DerivedGuestRoom`). By putting `HotelRoom()` you are using the default constructor. Maybe you can fix that, and then you really won't need it.

Comment: So just add the default implementation or remove from the derived class.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Right I have "DerivedMeetingRoom::DerivedMeetingRoom(int seat, int stat) : HotelRoom(), seats(seat), status(stat), (same also for DerivedGuestRoom). By putting HotelRoom()" because I have HotelRoom(char Num[], double daily, char* name);
    HotelRoom(const HotelRoom &);